# Proguard removing classes of log4j

Tags: android, log4j, apk, proguard, release

I am trying to generate the release variant APK and keep getting these errors:

```
Super class java.awt.event.KeyAdapter of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogFactor5InputDialog$1 is missing from classpath.
Super class java.awt.event.MouseAdapter of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.categoryexplorer.CategoryNodeEditor$2 is missing from classpath.
Super class java.awt.event.WindowAdapter of org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.Main$1 is missing from classpath.
Super class java.awt.event.WindowAdapter of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$LogBrokerMonitorWindowAdaptor is missing from classpath.
Super class javax.mail.Authenticator of org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender$1 is missing from classpath.
Super class javax.swing.AbstractAction of org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.ExitAction is missing from classpath.
Super class javax.swing.AbstractAction of org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.LoadXMLAction is missing from classpath.
Super class javax.swing.JDialog of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogFactor5Dialog is missing from classpath.
Super class javax.swing.JFrame of org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.Main is missing from classpath.
Super class javax.swing.JPanel of org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.ControlPanel is missing from classpath.
Super class javax.swing.JPanel of org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.DetailPanel is missing from classpath.
Super class javax.swing.JTable of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogTable is missing from classpath.
Super class javax.swing.JTree of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.categoryexplorer.CategoryExplorerTree is missing from classpath.
Super class javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel of org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.MyTableModel is missing from classpath.
Super class javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.FilteredLogTableModel is missing from classpath.
Super class javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogTableRowRenderer is missing from classpath.
Super class javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogTableModel is missing from classpath.
Super class javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.categoryexplorer.CategoryNode is missing from classpath.
Super class javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellEditor of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.categoryexplorer.CategoryImmediateEditor is missing from classpath.
Super class javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.categoryexplorer.CategoryNodeRenderer is missing from classpath.
Super class javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.categoryexplorer.CategoryExplorerModel is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.ControlPanel$1 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.ControlPanel$6 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.ControlPanel$7 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.categoryexplorer.CategoryNodeEditor$1 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.categoryexplorer.CategoryNodeEditor$3 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.categoryexplorer.CategoryNodeEditor$4 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.categoryexplorer.CategoryNodeEditor$5 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.categoryexplorer.CategoryNodeEditor$6 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.categoryexplorer.CategoryNodeEditor$7 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.categoryexplorer.CategoryNodeEditor$8 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$10 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$11 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$12 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$13 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$14 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$15 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$16 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$17 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$18 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$19 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$20 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$21 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$22 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$23 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$24 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$25 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$26 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$27 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$28 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$29 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$30 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$31 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$32 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$7 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$8 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogBrokerMonitor$9 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogFactor5ErrorDialog$1 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogFactor5InputDialog$2 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.ActionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogFactor5InputDialog$3 is missing from classpath.
Super interface java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.TrackingAdjustmentListener is missing from classpath.
Super interface javax.jms.MessageListener of org.apache.log4j.net.JMSSink is missing from classpath.
Super interface javax.management.DynamicMBean of org.apache.log4j.jmx.AbstractDynamicMBean is missing from classpath.
Super interface javax.management.MBeanRegistration of org.apache.log4j.jmx.AbstractDynamicMBean is missing from classpath.
Super interface javax.management.NotificationBroadcaster of org.apache.log4j.jmx.HierarchyDynamicMBean is missing from classpath.
Super interface javax.management.NotificationListener of org.apache.log4j.jmx.LoggerDynamicMBean is missing from classpath.
Super interface javax.swing.event.DocumentListener of org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.ControlPanel$2 is missing from classpath.
Super interface javax.swing.event.DocumentListener of org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.ControlPanel$3 is missing from classpath.
Super interface javax.swing.event.DocumentListener of org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.ControlPanel$4 is missing from classpath.
Super interface javax.swing.event.DocumentListener of org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.ControlPanel$5 is missing from classpath.
Super interface javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener of org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.DetailPanel is missing from classpath.
Super interface javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.LogTable$LogTableListSelectionListener is missing from classpath.
Super interface javax.swing.event.TreeModelListener of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.categoryexplorer.TreeModelAdapter is missing from classpath.
Super interface javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.categoryexplorer.CategoryAbstractCellEditor is missing from classpath.
Super interface javax.swing.tree.TreeCellEditor of org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.categoryexplorer.CategoryAbstractCellEditor is missing from classpath.
```

I am assuming for what I can inspect that it is a problem related with ProGuard removing classes. The library that might be the problem for this is jexcelapi

I am not very familiar with ProGuard yet, but I know it is possible to exclude the removal of specific classes. How can I prevent ProGuard from removing the aforementioned classes?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your progruard-rules.pro

-keep class org.apache.log4j.** { *; }

The `*;` means to keep everything inside the class.